# R: How to aggregate a list of dataframes by a single column, aggregating all columns at once

Tags: r, list, aggregate

Given a list of dataframes, like this

```
[[1]]
ID    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5
123   1    2    1    0    4
123   2    4    1    2    2
123   0    0    1    0    2
567   2    3    4    0    2
899   2    3    5    3    5

[[2]]
ID    X1   X2   X3   X4
123   7    1    3    2
452   1    3    6    3
899   2    1    4    2

[[3]]
ID    X1   X2   X3   X4   Y1
123   4    2    5    0    1
567   0    1    2    0    2
567   1    2    1    0    3
101   2    3    7    2    1
```

I want to aggregate all the dataframes by "ID" in all the other columns, the result in this illustration should be something like this

```
new_df
ID    X1   X2   X3   X4   X5   Y1
123   14   9    11   2    8    1
567   3    6    7    0    2    5    
899   4    4    9    5    5    0
452   1    3    6    3    0    0
101   2    3    7    2    0    1
```

This is only a illustration, the original list has 51 dfs and the original dfs have hundreds of columns, so the function cannot specify which columns will agreggate, instead should apply to all columns

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52449113/merge-2-data-frames-by-row-and-column-overlap

Comment: If the error happens with `bind_rows` ... perhaps `data.table::rbindlist` *might* be able to do it (I don't hold much confidence) ... perhaps your best bet is to normalize them (same columns names, meaning you'll need to "fill" some empty columns), dump them to a single file, then try again. How disparate are the columns? That is, in the example you provided, there is a column missing from 1 to 2, then a new column in 3 ... are the number of differences relatively small (1s or 2s) or do they vary significantly?

Comment: data.table::rbindlist didnt work. The columns are very disparate, there are about 22-40 columns in each df and all of them are different from each other. What repeat are the IDs

Comment: Now it worked!
I aggregated each one of the DFs in the list individually, since the columns in the original list are different from each other, and then merged all the dfs with reduce

Answer (score 3):

We can use `dplyr::summarize_all`

```
# some sample data (different from yours, just to illustrate)
df_list = list(
  data.frame(ID = c(123, 123, 234), x1 = c(1, 2, 3), x2 = 2:4),
  data.frame(ID = c(123, 123, 234), x1 = c(1, 2, 3), x2 = 2:4, x3 = 4:6),
  data.frame(ID = c(123, 123), x1 = c(1, 2), x3 = 2:3)
)

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df_list) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all("sum", na.rm = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#      ID    x1    x2    x3
#   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
# 1   123     9    10    14
# 2   234     6     8     6
```

---

Edits: Since you're bumping up against memory constraints, the best you can do in `dplyr` is to aggregate each data frame individually, thus reducing it's size, before combining and aggregating again. I would suggest a simple `for` loop approach to avoid trying to copy all the data at once:

```
for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  df_list[[i]] = df_list[[i]] %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize_all("sum", na.rm = TRUE)
}
# Then use the code from above
result = bind_rows(df_list) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all("sum", na.rm = TRUE)
```

The extent to which this will help depends completely on how much ID repetition there is within each data frame. If this still doesn't work then the next thing to try would be using `data.table`, which allows modifications in place:

```
library(data.table)

for (i in seq_along(df_list)) {
  setDT(df_list[[i]]) # convert data frames to data.tables
  # pre-aggregate to reduce size
  df_list[[i]] = df_list[[i]][ , lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(ID)]  
}

# combine and aggregate
big_dt = rbindlist(df_list, fill = TRUE)
big_dt = big_dt[ , lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(ID)]
```

The `data.table` solution should be quite memory efficient. If you still run into memory problems, make sure your workspace is as empty as possible and you don't have other applications eating up memory either. If that doesn't work, turn to the R-FAQ [Cannot allocate vector of size n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5171593/903061) for additional tips (like using a computer with more memory or using packages that allow for out-of-memory calculations).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunatelly, it didn't work, due to memory, giving the error:
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 18.2 Mb

Answer (score 1):

```
> microbenchmark(
+     test1 <- df_list %>% 
+     ldply %>% 
+     group_by(ID) %>% 
+     summarize_all('sum', na.rm=TRUE), 
+     
+     test2 <- df_list %>% 
+         ldply %>% 
+         ddply(.(ID), summarize, 
+               x1 = sum(x1, na.rm=TRUE), 
+               x2 = sum(x2, na.rm=TRUE), 
+               x3 = sum(x3, na.rm=TRUE)), 
+     
+     test3 <- df_list %>% 
+         bind_rows %>% 
+         group_by(ID) %>% 
+         summarize_all('sum', na.rm=TRUE), 
+     
+     test4 <- df_list %>% 
+         bind_rows %>% 
+         ddply(.(ID), summarize, 
+               x1 = sum(x1, na.rm=TRUE), 
+               x2 = sum(x2, na.rm=TRUE), 
+               x3 = sum(x3, na.rm=TRUE)), 
+     
+     test5 <- rbindlist(df_list, fill = TRUE) %>% 
+         .[ , lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(ID)]
+     )
Unit: milliseconds

  expr
  test1 <- df_list %>% ldply %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize_all("sum", na.rm = TRUE)
  test2 <- df_list %>% ldply %>% ddply(.(ID), summarize, x1 = sum(x1, na.rm = TRUE), x2 = sum(x2, na.rm = TRUE), x3 = sum(x3, na.rm = TRUE))
  test3 <- df_list %>% bind_rows %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize_all("sum", na.rm = TRUE)
  test4 <- df_list %>% bind_rows %>% ddply(.(ID), summarize, x1 = sum(x1, na.rm = TRUE), x2 = sum(x2, na.rm = TRUE), x3 = sum(x3, na.rm = TRUE))
  test5 <- rbindlist(df_list, fill = TRUE) %>% .[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = .(ID)]
          min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
     2.798383 2.977228 3.147271 3.130156 3.279235  3.840657   100   c
     2.797870 3.034704 3.408260 3.220733 3.340305 22.279300   100   c
     2.146642 2.309835 2.633888 2.429919 2.563603 20.407723   100  b 
     2.254924 2.431202 2.598176 2.533325 2.688306  3.581499   100  b 
     1.209571 1.331708 1.430511 1.423055 1.508243  2.172301   100 a
```

Here I compare the efficiency of answers provided by @Gregor.